# Most idiomatic way to create cycled and infinite range of integers in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

In ruby you can do something like this

```rb
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
a.cycle {|x| puts x }  # print, a, b, c, a, b, c,.. forever.
a.cycle(2) {|x| puts x }  # print, a, b, c, a, b, c.
```

and this is just beautiful.

The closest analog in Java 8 would be like this:

```java
Stream<Integer> iterator = Stream.iterate(new int[] {0, 0}, p -> new int[]{p[0] + 1, (p[0] + 1) % 2}).map(el -> el[1]);
Iterator<Integer> iter = iterator.iterator();
System.out.println(iter.next());//0
System.out.println(iter.next());//1
System.out.println(iter.next());//0
System.out.println(iter.next());//1
```

Is there a better way and more idiomatic to do it in Java?

**Update**

Just want to outline here that the closest solution to my problem was

```
IntStream.generate(() -> max).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i))
```

Thanks to @Hogler

Comment: Just want to outline here that the closest solution to my problem was IntStream.generate(() -> max).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i)) Thanks to @Hogler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
Stream.generate(() -> array).flatMap(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

to print `a` `b` `c` forever and

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
Stream.generate(() -> array).limit(2).flatMap(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

to print `a` `b` `c` two times.

This doesn’t even require an existing array:

```
Stream.generate(() -> null)
      .flatMap(x -> Stream.of("a", "b", "c"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

resp.

```
Stream.generate(() -> null).limit(2)
      .flatMap(x -> Stream.of("a", "b", "c"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

you could also use

```
IntStream.range(0, 2).boxed()
      .flatMap(x -> Stream.of("a", "b", "c"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: well, I *was* going to edit my answer with `flatMap`... too late I guess

Comment: @holger slightly modified question: in the very beginning I know only maximum value, lets say, 2 and the sourcing array would be 0, 1. For 3 it would be 0, 1, 2. In this way I can generate a sourcing array first and use it later as you pointed out. But maybe there is a better way to do it? Actually, this is was my initial question

Comment: Perhaps, you mean like `IntStream.generate(() -> max).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i))`

Answer (score 3):

Well if you define the array variable outside the stream, you can use indexes instead. And you will have something like:

```java
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };

Stream.iterate(0, i -> (i + 1) % array.length)
        .map(i -> array[i])
        .forEach(System.out::println); // prints a, b, c forever

Stream.iterate(0, i -> (i + 1) % array.length)
        .map(i -> array[i])
        .limit(2 * array.length)
        .forEach(System.out::println); // prints a, b, c 2 times
```

Also can use [nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)) you don't need to use `array.length`:

```java
Collections.nCopies(2, array).stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println); // prints a, b, c 2 times
```

It is obviously longer than the ruby version, but that's how usually java is (more verbose)

Comment: `Collections.nCopies(2, array).stream()` produces the same as `IntStream.range(0, 2) .mapToObj(i -> array)` in the current implementation. Just in case someone wants to know…

Comment: Why is that relevant?, `boxed()` uses `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`.

Comment: As said, “just in case someone wants to know”. That means, it is not a relevant thing, but rather a trivia. The most interesting thing about it, is, that you can also use the equivalent `IntStream.range(0, 2) .mapToObj(i -> array)`. Knowing both variants may help to derive solutions for other related problems. By the way, in Java 9, `boxed()` does not use exactly `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)` anymore, but rather a variant that keeps the knowledge that the objects are sorted and distinct.

Comment: Ok, good we both agreed is not relevant, my comment about `boxed()` in a similar way, it is also in case someone needs to know. The method `nCopies` is more 'idiomatic' than using `mapToObj`. And about java9 still uses `mapToObj` just that it doesn't use the `NOT_SORTED` and `NOT_DISTINCT` flags, meaning is sorted and distinct aware (but again just applies for sorted or distinct streams, not this variant).

Comment: Well, `IntStream.range(…).boxed()` *is* sorted and distinct, but of course, the subsequent `flatMap` step will clear these properties. You already have my upvote, there’s nothing more I can do to state that you have shown viable alternatives.

Comment: This variant does includes the `flatMap`, so it doesn't matter that the previous stream was `sorted` or `distinct`. Anyway your 1st and 2nd (using the array) solution (in my personal opinion) are more readable than indexes or `nCopy`.